# Synaptics Touchpad not working

Tags: windows, touchpad, scrolling

Since I have updated windows 7 ultimate to windows 10 pro, my touchpad scroll is not working.
I have tried everything but not working so far.
Anyone who get it working?
Acer aspire laptop 7730

Comment: Which "everything" have you tried? In order for people to help you your question needs to give details of what you have tried. You can [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/951553/edit) your question to add more details.

Comment: So you have installed the [Windows 10 Synaptic](http://drivers.synaptics.com/Synaptics_v17_0_19_C_XP32_Vista32_Win7-32_XP64_Vista64_Win7-64_Acme_Inc.zip) drivers offered by Synaptic?  Although it does not specifically list Windows 10, this driver, does indeed support Windows 10 based on the fact [v16](http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/downloads/DS032247) supported it.  It is very unlikely your hardware will receive official support for Windows 10 by Acer due to its age.

Comment: [Here is a list of products Acer will support with Windows 10](http://us.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/windows10-eligible-models) anything else is unlikely to fully function.  The generic driver approach is the best you will do, even the version I linked to, might not work.  You might have to wait for a driver that specifically indicates Windows 10 support until it does work.

Answer (score -1):

I cannot comment and you have not posted enough information but here's the rough layout of what you need to do and check. I hope this approach helps.

- When you do an in-place upgrade from one Windows OS to another the existing OEM drivers you had could have been over written or replaced by default new Windows OS drivers, which do not support all kinds of things that OEM specific drivers did or do.

  - Best thing for you to do is find updated drivers from the OEM - Acer for your laptop and OS (Win 10), which may take some time as Win 10 was just released
  - You could look for updated drivers from Synaptics as a second option
  - If none of this works right now, wait until they come
  - If you'd like to fix this right away, and do not wish to wait, it might be possible to "force install" OEM drivers from previous OSes on top of Windows 10 under compatibility.

Since I do not have an Acer machine or access to specific information, and given that lot of people will face this issue as they upgrade from Win 7/8 to Win 10, this is the approach you and them need to follow.

Comment: What attack do you speak of?  The comment I submitted is generated by the system, designed to be used, when a comment was submitted as an answer.  You literally state in your answer, that you would have submitted it as a comment, if you had the reputation to do so.  You don't explain in detail how to do ANY of those things.  For instance how exactly does one force install a driver?  Where does one find the Windows 10 generic driver from Synaptic when one actually isn't posted?  Acer will not be updating updated drives for the author's device so why point him there?

Comment: You can easily improve this answer, and explain how the user forces the installation of a driver, which if you can confirm would solve his problem would be an answer to their question.  Acer has a published list of which devices support Windows 10, the author's device, is not on that list.

Comment: @Ramhound - Ok. I will try to find a relevant link/ example and steps on how force installing of drivers is done - But it wont be Acer specific :) PS: But that will be over the weekend as I have other things to tackle.